# split horizontal two layout on a single layout with a title on top

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

i am trying to make a layout which looks like this:[image]

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i know how to do that two horizontal layouts, but i dont know how to put another layout on top. I am using scroll view so i cannot put another child layout. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Try this. ScrollView allows only one child layout. Define that child layout and in that child layout you can add multiple layouts.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
           // Your top layout
           // Add your compont(s)
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1">
                   // Add your compont(s)
             </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1">
                   // Add your compont(s)
               </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```